# How to gracefully handle an infinite loop in a GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that implements an infinite loop using while (true) in a Java application. The application is an ApplicationRunner and listens to Kafka messages. The workflow is triggered on each push to the repository.

However, this leads to the workflow running indefinitely in a loop. I understand that GitHub Actions may not be intended for such long-running processes. Nevertheless, I would like to find a way to handle this gracefully.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    private Consumer<String, String> consumer;
    @Autowired
    protected KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(kafkaConsumerProperties.getPollTimeout()));
            if (!records.isEmpty()) {
                consumeRecords(records);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`release.yml`:

```yaml
  - name: Publish artifact to nexus
    run: >
      mvn deploy -Dnexus_username=${{ secrets.NEXUS_USERNAME }} -Dnexus_password=${{ secrets.NEXUS_PASSWORD }}
      -DaltDeploymentRepository=${{ secrets.NEXUS_RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REPO_URL }}
      -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true 
      -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true 
      -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```